# Automatic addition to hdaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

this code snippet was added to my .htaccess after I installed a plugin.

Is my site viral?

Is this normal?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some plugins adds some snippets to the `.htaccess` specially the security plugins and cache plugins, the one you wrote is the basic WP `.htaccess` file, so I don't think there would be a problem.